# Symfony2 user registration form example from official docs

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms, symfony-2.1, user-registration

I suppose there is something wrong in [this](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/registration_form.html) example for a simple user registration form in *Symfony2.x*.  In particular, I suppose that there is no setting of the user data. For instance, the `setUser()` function from `Registration` class is never used.

Am I right?

If the answer is 'Yes', where should the `setUser()` function be called?

If the answer is 'No', so why to define that function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this function is used. It is used by Symfony when it needs to set the $user property of your registration object, for example when the form is bound. You don´t need to "call" it, it will be called by Symfony when needed.

Comment: So Symfony uses the field name user to look for a setUser function. Now I understood. Thanks

Comment: Yes, this is a common convention: if you have a property called 'whatever' then its setter and getter should be 'setWhatever()' and 'getWhatever()'

Comment: I poster this question because the validation is not working and so I was supposing that the problem was that no user were set. Of course, the problem should be another!

Comment: I said that I had a problem in validating the form. Now I understood that the problem is due to a missing **'cascade_validation' => true,** in the options of the RegistrationType form. I'm sad that this is not mentioned in the official docs. An example about a user registration form should take care of validation.